# Give a round image a round border

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%Color/Tikz
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myRed}{HTML}{ff6347}
\definecolor{myOrange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (.15\columnwidth,0) {\includegraphics[width=.7\columnwidth]{froggy}};
\draw[black,ultra thick,rounded corners] (7.5,5.3) circle (.35\columnwidth);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

While it "works" somehow, it's not perfect. Can someone please help me? This is the part I don't get right:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (.15\columnwidth,0) {\includegraphics[width=.7\columnwidth]{froggy}};
\draw[black,ultra thick,rounded corners] (7.5,5.3) circle (.35\columnwidth);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Problem: the border almost covers the image correctly. But there is like a mm too much / too little at the tom corner and the left bottom. And this tiny little stuff is what is driving me nuts.

**Problem in images**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ZXn.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFDOj.png)

Comment: Does your question change, if you use `example-image-a` (an image, that other people have) instead of `froggy`?

Comment: Why do you give your circle rounded corners?

Comment: I do not fully understand your problem, as I can not see your result. Include a picture, and draw an arrow to the problematic area. What if you add `outer sep=0` to your `\node` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`skins` library from `tcolorbox` adds options to `TikZ` which allow to fill a path with a defined image or picture:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black,ultra thick,fill zoom image=frog] (7.5,5.3) circle (.35\columnwidth);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black,ultra thick,fill zoom image=frog, rounded corners] (0,0)--(45:3cm)-|++(3,-5)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very beautiful. Very interesting is your solution. I put your solution among my favorites.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Exactly what I tried but couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 3):

I do not fully understand your question, as I do not have the `froggy` image. Here I have removed the unused code and replaced `froggy` with `example-image-a`. By making `outer sep=0` and subtracting the line width from the circle diameter, it covers the image perfectly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[width=.7\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
\draw[ultra thick] (.35\columnwidth, .35\columnwidth) circle (.35\columnwidth-0.5\pgflinewidth);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image with circle]