# Format picture and text with TikZ and minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, cv

I want to format the upper part of my CV, but I have encountered two problems:

1. I want to format the picture to be perfectly round and make sure the
   whole picture is within the frame. However, when I start touching the framing the picture "looses" its roundness.
2. I want to **format my header like the picture below**: where I have a round picture to the left, then a box with my name and small text below. However, working with minipages I have not been able to produce the desired result.

[image]

Here is my working code at this moment:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,8 pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{underscore}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\newcommand{\at}{\makeatletter @\makeatother}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{1em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    \hspace*{-3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(frog.center),inner sep=0pt]
    \clip (0,0)  circle (2cm) node (frog) {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{frog.jpg}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    \vspace{-1.5cm} \centerline{\Huge \textbf{My Name Here}}
\end{minipage} 
%\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    \vspace{0cm} \hspace{-2cm}\begin{tabular}{rl}
        \textsc{Email:} & My_eMail\at gmail.com \\ 
        \textsc{Telefon:} & \ xxx \ xx \ xxx \\
        \textsc{Sted:} & xxxx, xxxxx \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Make the graphic larger, e.g. \includegraphics[width=8cm] then it will get round.

Comment: Alexander Lightwood also asked about a round picture(and he also used a frog as an example). Maybe you can use something from his answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466265/give-a-round-image-a-round-border

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could put everything in one `tikzpicture`. As you want the circle the same size as the box, it makes sense to make the box first, and then set the size of the circle to the same as the height of the box.

Note by the way that `8 pt` is not a valid option for the `article` class, it doesn't do anything. `10pt` (default), `11pt` and `12pt` are the ones available by default.

The outer frame in this screenshot comes from having added the `showframe` option to the the `geometry` package. With that option a frame is added around the text area.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{underscore}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\newcommand{\at}{\makeatletter @\makeatother}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % loads tikz which loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{1em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
%\hfill
\noindent\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
     boxwidth=\textwidth-4cm; % you may need to change 4cm so something else, depending on the height of the box
     boxinnersep=2mm; 
     }
  ]
    \node [
       text width=boxwidth,
       align=left,
       draw,
       fill=green!30,
       inner sep=boxinnersep] (box) {%
       {\Huge \textbf{My Name Here}} \\[5pt]
       \begin{tabular}{rl}
        \textsc{Email:} & MyeMail\at gmail.com \\ 
        \textsc{Telefon:} & \ xxx \ xx \ xxx \\
        \textsc{Sted:} & xxxx, xxxxx \\
    \end{tabular}
    };       

    \path
    let
       \p1=(box.north),
       \p2=(box.south),
       \n1={\y1-\y2},
       \n2={(\textwidth-boxwidth-\n1-2*boxinnersep-2\pgflinewidth)/2}
    in
    node [
      minimum size=\n1,
      circle,
      path picture={
         \node [anchor=center] {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}};
         },
      left=\n2 of box
      ] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to format the picture as the same height as the box? And, is it possible to have the box cover the enitre width of the page?

Comment: @Ola Do you want to make the image smaller or the box higher?

Comment: Image smaller. Thanks for the swift replies!¨

Comment: For the width of the page, use `text width={\dimexpr \textwidth - 4cm - 4mm}`

Comment: @Ola I updated the answer a few minutes ago.

Comment: Nicely done, thanks! Are there any flexibility if I, say, want to move the picture more to the right?

Comment: @Ola For example you could change `\nodindent` to `\noindent\hfill`, and make `\n2` smaller (e.g. divide by 2, `\n2={(\textwidth-boxwidth-\n1-2*boxinnersep-2\pgflinewidth)/2}`).